# Как заполнить словарь по совпадающему ключу?

Tags: python, list, dict

Как заполнить словарь значениями списка по совпадению 1-го элемента списка?
Есть исходный словарь:

```
{'orders': [{'id': '1', 'num': '22', 'prices': []}, {'id': '2', 'num': '33', 'prices': []}]}
```

и список:

```
[['22', 'shop1', '$25'], [22, 'shop2', '$35'], ['33', 'shop1', '$100']]
```

где 1-элемент это число, которое должно соответствовать полю 'num' 1-го словаря.
То есть если '22' является значениям ключа 'num', то мы добавляем 2 и 3 элементы списка в ключ 'prices'.
На выходе хочется получить:

```
{'orders': [{'id': '1', 'num': '22', 'prices': ['shop1', '$25', 'shop2', '$35']}, {'id': '2', 'num': '33', 'prices': ['shop1', '$100']}]}
```

Пытался сделать с помощью вложенного цикла и проверять совпадения, но это очень долго, так как данных очень много, можно ли это сделать как-нибудь иначе, или изначально по-другому задать исходный словарь, чтобы хранить значения 'prices', чтобы потом использовать в api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь превратил двумерный список в массив numpy, для удобства и еще он работает быстрее чем обычный массив, более гибок к извлечению элементов. Так же одно значение 22 типа int. Это вы опечатались или специально так сделали?
Вы сказали, что использовали вложенный цикл, а значит их у Вас как минимум два. Может, кто и предложит варианты вообще без циклов(у меня он один в две итерации).

```
import numpy as np
import more_itertools as mit

aaa = {'orders': [{'id': '1', 'num': '22', 'prices': []}, {'id': '2', 'num': '33', 'prices': []}]}
arr = np.array([['22', 'shop1', '$25'], [22, 'shop2', '$35'], ['33', 'shop1', '$100']])


iterable = arr[:, 0]
for i in aaa['orders']:
    index = list(mit.locate(iterable, lambda x: x in i['num']))
    if len(index) < 1:
       continue
    b = arr[index, 1:]
    if len(index) > 1:
        cou = b.shape[0] + b.shape[1]# количество элементов
        yyy = list(b.reshape(cou,))
    else:
        yyy = list(b[0])#если список один
    i['prices'] = yyy

print(aaa)
```

Comment: Да, ошибся, спасибо.

Comment: в numpy 22 превратилась все равно в строку.

Comment: Что нужно изменить в коде, если например, в листе будет не 2 элемента с 'num': '22', а больше?

Comment: И кстати, если вместо '33' например ввести '34', то будет ошибка 'IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0', это фиксить только через try except?

Comment: На счет 34 сделал проверку на пустой список индексов: if len(index) < 1. С несколькими 22 это имеете ввиду в списке arr?

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался.